# Event-wait task in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Which of the following statements is correct on workflow events?

1) A predefined (or file-wait) Event Wait task waits for a file to appear at the specified location. As soon as the file appears, the event succeeds and the file can be processed by the subsequent mapping.

2) A predefined (or file-wait) Event Wait waits for a file to appear at the specified location. As soon as the file appears, it is deleted and the subsequent task will start.

Comment: option 1 is true. If its selected then only event wait will delete the watcher file. Mandatory requirement is - Infa should have read access to that file.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 is true**. By default *Informatica* doesn't delete the file watch for which the predefined event is waiting.

If you want the file to be deleted as soon as the subsequent task is started, you will have to check the 'Delete Filewatch File' option which is present in properties tab of Event wait task. 
[Delete Filewatch File property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YByoP.jpg)